# Cake logging with colours

Tags: cakebuild

I've read about cake's [console aliases](https://cakebuild.net/dsl/logging/).

Is it possible to log using colours?

For example, I'd log success / warning / error in green / orange / red:

```cs
CustomWarning("WARN: Foo bar baz!");    // orange text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cake comes with [Spectre.Console](https://spectreconsole.net/) as documented here: https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/console-output#advanced-output.

You can use it to print out formatted text:

```
AnsiConsole.Write(new Markup("[bold yellow]Hello[/] [red]World![/]"));
```

To have all logs, including the ones from Cake itself or addins, replaced, you can write a [custom module](https://cakebuild.net/docs/extending/modules/) with an `ICakeLog` implementation which uses Spectre.Console to write log messages.

See https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.BuildSystems.Module for an example of an module which implements custom logging.

Answer (score 0):

[Use](https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/console-output#advanced-output) "Spectre.Console" [instead](https://spectreconsole.net/):

```cs
#r "Spectre.Console"
using Spectre.Console
// ...
AnsiConsole.MarkupLine("[bold orangered1]WARN:[/] Foo bar baz!");
```